# Link "get avatar" to a completely different website

Tags: php, wordpress, footer, avatar

I'm having a WordPress multi site installed and i using a fixed footer that shows on all blogs. I've put the "blogfooter.php" that is the name of the footer on for example "static.mydomain.com" and "mydomain.com/blog" have used iframe to get that php file into the themes and added css code for it etc.

However now i'm wondering how to write php for getting the avatar of a certain blog (id) showed in that file (blogfooter.php) so it's dynamic. When the bloguser changes the avatar of the admin of the blog (editor in this case, but the owner). So i can't figure out how to show a avatar in a file that doesn't is in the WordPress folders. The width and the height should be 35px.

I'm using the plugin "User Avatar" (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-avatar/) for changing the profilepicture. So how do i do this?

Comment: why you dont use native avatar feature on wordrpess, gravatar, it link you profile picture to gravatar by an email. no need to store avatar images at server at all.

Comment: you dont need to use iframe to get another file. there is a way http://codex.wordpress.org/Include_Tags

Comment: It's because i want to do this very simple and easy for the users to change their profilepicture. I think it will be tedious for the blogusers to get an account etc to just change the profilepicture. Can i use the include tags when the file isn't anywhere near the wordpress installation? Can i for example put the include tag if just the file is on another server? I thought them where for if i had the file in the same folder as the theme itself?